# Блокировка сайтов C#

Tags: c#

Есть программа, которая при переходе на определенный сайт (к примеру http://example.com) должна блокировать доступ, выводя текст на подобии "доступ к сайту запрещен" вместо страницы сайта. Я думаю, что надо использовать программу в качестве прокси сервера.
Кто знает, подскажите, каким образом будет лучше это сделать, и если есть небольшой пример, то как. Буду благодарен любому совету.

Comment: Вам прям 100% решение или так, для галочки? Если второе, то самое банальное - настроить файл `hosts`, где будет подмена домена на нужный ip, указываете там локальный, приложением поднимаете мини HTTP сервер со страничкой заглушкой, готово. Если всеж надо надежно, то тут да, скорей всего нужен прокси или нечто подобное, чтоб быть между клиентом и сервером. Вообще, обычно такая штука делается на стороне роутеров и другого сетевого оборудования, а не на стороне клиента.

Comment: C# для таких штук не нужен, примерно совсем, как и любой другой язык программирования. Весь требуемый софт уже давно написан. Если прокси, то squid, 3poxy в помощь. Ну или ALG поверх NAT, если роутер умеет.

Comment: Hosts не решит проблемы, если, допустим, нам надо разрешить доступ только к одному сайту. Как лучше реализовать это?